# high CPU usage with ffmpeg and youtube live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, live-streaming

I have a problem with high CPU usage using FFmpeg to stream my videos via youtube.
my main purpose is to stream loop videos as long as possible but after 6 hours the stream stops and the CPU usage was almost 90%.

the code I'm using

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 3368k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -f flv -s 1280x720 -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxx
```

My VPS details:
1 vCPU, 3 GB memory

Comment: Try with `-preset superfast -profile:v baseline`. Is the scaling required?

Comment: no, the scaling is not required, my CPU utilization now is between 40%-50%

Comment: is there any room left to reduce more?

Comment: If the video.mp4 is already 4:2:0 H264 with the correct KF interval, you can skip video re-encoding.

Comment: sorry I'm not very techy about FFmpeg, what should I delete from the command above to skip video re-encoding

Comment: `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -c copy -f flv max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: I got an error "Unable to find a suitable output format for '400' 400: Invalid argument"

Comment: Typo, it's `-max_muxing_queue_size 400`

Comment: it's working smoothly, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not your CPU, instat the RAM and your hard drive are not able to handle the traffic anymore, and your CPU try to calculate it smaller. Pleas list up your setup, beacuse without knowing your Setup we cant help you.

Comment: I think you are right, I've tried the solution above and I reduced the CPU  usage by the half but  I still got the same problem. I'm using 3gb ram with 30gb  SSD on window server 2016, the size of the video I'm using is 16 MB